# running ISPC on UBUNTU 32 bit

Tags: ubuntu, parallel-processing, ispc

I have 32 Ubuntu 14.0 installed, can I Install and use ISPC(Intel SPDM program compiler) on it? If yes then how? if not then why? I have tried multiple times but did not find an appropriate answer.. Thank you in advance